# How to force the extended line in Tikz picture stay in the box

Tags: tikz-pgf, boxes

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{most}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}{%
    colback=yellow,
    hbox
    }
\begin{document}    
\begin{mybox}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    plotmark/.style = {solid, fill, circle, inner sep = 0pt, minimum size = 4pt}]
    \node [plotmark,label={below:$A$}] (A) at (0,0) {};
    \node [plotmark,label={below:$B$}] (B) at (3,1) {};
    \draw[shorten >=-2cm] (A)--(B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I had the same problem with `fbox` (the same problem occurs without `hbox` option of `tcolorbox`).

Comment: You are using TikZ to draw the points, nodes and line! -are there any reason why you are not also using TikZ to draw the yellow box?

Answer (score 4):

If you *do* need the `tcolorbox`, you can solve your problem with the `enhanced` and the `clip upper` options.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{most}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}{%
    enhanced,
    colback=yellow,
    hbox,
    clip upper
}
\begin{document}
\begin{mybox}
\begin{tikzpicture}[plotmark/.style = {solid, fill, circle, inner sep = 0pt, minimum size = 4pt}]
    \node [plotmark,label={below:$A$}] (A) at (0,0) {};
    \node [plotmark,label={below:$B$}] (B) at (3,1) {};
    \draw[shorten >=-2cm] (A)--(B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I made the box in TikZ as I can not see if you really require the `tcolorbox`!?

I made the box some random size with extra large corners, so you can see that the line correctly stays inside -you can addjust as needed.

```
\documentclass[border = 1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
  plotmark/.style = {solid, fill, circle, inner sep = 0pt, minimum
    size = 4pt}
  ]
  \draw[fill=yellow, rounded corners=1 cm] (-1,-1) rectangle (4,2);
  \clip[rounded corners= 1cm] (-1,-1) rectangle (4,2);
  \node [plotmark,label={below:$A$}] (A) at (0,0) {};
  \node [plotmark,label={below:$B$}] (B) at (3,1) {};
  \draw[shorten >=-2cm] (A)--(B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: yellow rectangle with line inside]

Right now the line is not touching `A` -that can be amended by adding `outer sep = 0 pt` to the `plotmark` style.